# SwiftUI: horizontal ScrollView inside NavigationLink breaks navigation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-scrollview

I want to use a simple horizontal `ScrollView` as `NavigationLink` inside a `List`. However, tapping on the `ScrollView` is not registered by a `NavigationLink` and therefore does not navigate to the destination.

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail")) {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                Text("Tapping here does not navigate.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how can we prevent `ScrollView` from capturing the navigation tap gesture?

Answer (score 3):

You can move `NavigationLink` to the `background` and activate it in `onTapGesture`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLinkActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    Text("Tapping here does not navigate.")
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    isLinkActive = true
                }
            }
            .background(
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail"), isActive: $isLinkActive) {}
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but it's a hack/workaround I'm already aware of and was trying to avoid with a potential native approach. Thanks!

Comment: @damirstuhec What you've tried in your question looks like it should (probably) be the *native* way. But it's not (at least in SwiftUI 2). So you might still need to use workarounds/hacks (as you often do with SwiftUI).

Comment: Agree. It feels like a bug, so let's hope that's fixed soon. I filed feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The final goal is not clear, but the following alternate does also work (tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14)

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail")) {
                Text("Tapping here does not navigate.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, however, I simplified my question example a bit too much. In reality, I want a navigation link row, which contains other views besides the scroll view. Moving the ScrollView outside of the NavigationLink, as you're suggesting, would make the whole row contents scroll, which is not what I want.